# Null result web services android

Tags: android

SOAP web service in android .

I try below code but I got null result every time.

I post each and every detail which I know.

```
  private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://184.168.70.56/VideoStreamingService/UserService.svc/UserLogin";     
      private static String NAMESPACE = "http://184.168.70.56/";
      private static String METHOD_NAME = "UserLogin";      
      private static String URL = "http://184.168.70.56/VideoStreamingService/UserService.svc";
```

public void call() {
        try {

```
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        request.addProperty("userName",userNameET.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("password",passWordET.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("deviceToken","0000AAAABBBBCCCC");
        request.addProperty("deviceFlag","1");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

        //to get the data
        String resultData = result.toString();
        // 0 is the first object of data 

        Log.e("resultdata1", resultData);
       // sb.append(resultData + "\n");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        //sb.append("Error:\n" + e.getMessage() + "\n");
            Log.e("resultdata", String.valueOf( e.getMessage()));
        }

    }
```